# How do I get id(ArrayList with id and Setvices) when I clicked spinner items?

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Model model = new Model("1","GYM");
    Model model1 = new Model("2","Football");
    Model model2 = new Model("3","Cricket");
    Model model3 = new Model("4","VolleyBall");
    //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it
    spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the country list
    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayList<Model> arraylist = new ArrayList<Model>(); // This is actually the list created from the HashMap
    arraylist.add(model);
    arraylist.add(model1);
    arraylist.add(model2);

    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Model>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraylist);
    spin.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
    Model selectedItem = (Model) spin.getSelectedItem(); // Object which was selected.
    selectedItem.getService_iD(); // This will give you the ID of the item selected. Do whatever you wish with to do.

    Log.e("asdfgg", "onCreate: "+   selectedItem.getService_iD());

    Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: " +model.getService_iD());

}

//Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {


    Model selectedItem = (Model) spin.getSelectedItem(); // Object which was selected.
    selectedItem.getService_iD(); // Th

    Log.e("fdfda", "onItemSelected: "+ selectedItem.getService_iD() );

}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I am showing data(Service_Name) of 2nd index of my ArrayList objects when spinner opened but I want to get(in logcat) ArrayList objects data at first index (Service_Id)corresponding to which item is clicked over spinner when I click the spinner items